# Embed OpenSSL module in Swift framework so its not needed when importing into application

Tags: ios, swift, module, frameworks, openssl

I have a similar problem as this (unaswered) one: [Swift app: “Missing required module” when importing framework that imports static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757417/swift-app-missing-required-module-when-importing-framework-that-imports-stati)
But my static library is not as a (sub)project, only linked to my framework which is together with an application in one workspace.

So what I need is to include OpenSSL in my framework so when I give it to someone, he doesn't need to link OpenSSL to his application because it is already included in my framework.

I built OpenSSL and have libcrypto.a, libssl.a and corresponding header files.
I created modulemap to make this visible in my swift framework.

```
module COpenssl {
    umbrella header "openssl.h"
    export *
}
```

When I run tests on this framework everything works as intented.

But when I use my framework named 'lib' (import lib) in an application I get the error: Missing required module 'COpenssl'

I tried this command to check if OpenSSL is bundled into my framework:

```
$nm ./lib.framework/lib | grep SHA256_
0000000000096820 T external _SHA256_Final
0000000000096540 T external _SHA256_Init
0000000000097d40 T external _SHA256_Transform
00000000000966c0 T external _SHA256_Update
00000000001faf70 S external _SHA256_version
```

Based on this I assume that OpenSSL is there.

Why is the application trying to find COpenssl module when it doesn't need it?

XCode 8.0 (8A218a), Swift 2.3

Comment: is it even possible to bundle a static library with swift framework?

Comment: indicated answer wasn't helpfull at all, I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072619/1646117